# Downloading SRTM data

Tags: data, download, srtm

Is there an easy way to mass download SRTM data?  The data is published for download [here](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/), but it's sliced into thousands of small files, and I don't see an FTP option for more efficient downloading...  Another issue is that the server seems to die (or run out of bandwidth) when I use a download manager like the "DownThemAll" Firefox extension to get them.

Is there a better resource for getting this data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update:
I think wget would be better, i just don't use it very often:

`wget -r -A.zip http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/`

Also see for some retrieval wait options (if you want to be courteous):
https://superuser.com/questions/178297/wget-terminates-unexpectedly/178326#178326

You could curl the files with a little bit of text editor work.

[image]

For curl, the man page is here:
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Download here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

I think there are throttling and retry options (check the above-mentioned man page).

```
curl -O http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Australia/S11E119.hgt.zip
curl -O http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Australia/S11E120.hgt.zip
curl -O http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Australia/S11E121.hgt.zip
curl -O http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Australia/S11E122.hgt.zip
curl -O http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Australia/S11E123.hgt.zip
```

---

In addition to Jay's excellent pointers, I would recommend using the `--timestamping` flag when downloading so you can only get files that are newer than on your file system (really useful when your downloading gets interrupted).

Additionally, using the `--no-parent` flag means that only the SRTM3 directory is downloaded  rather than it continuing up the tree to the other directories.

The full wget commandline I'm using:

`wget -r --no-parent --random-wait --timestamping -A.zip http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/`

Comment: the list of curl statements is cut off due to character limits for  stackexchange answers...but you get the idea.

Comment: wget works fantastically!  It seems to behave well enough (not hammering the server) so it's not bombing out even though it's automated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can download and clip a portion of the SRTM 30m DEM with one command with the [elevation](http://elevation.bopen.eu/en/stable/quickstart.html) Python command line tool.

Install it and perform the self check with:

```
$ pip install elevation
```

Check if you have all the dependencies installed (mainly GDAL tools):

```
$ eio selfcheck
```

Download and clip a portion of the SRTM 30m DEM giving bounding box as WGS84 coordinates:

```
$ eio clip -o Rome-DEM.tif --bounds 12.35 41.8 12.65 42
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net) to download SRTM tiles automatically and unzip them. Just zoom in/out to the area of your interest and it will download all the required tiles to your disk. And best of all, it's free.

Here's a [sample hillshading + hypsometric rendering](http://www.flickr.com/photos/breki74/4794474306/sizes/o/in/photostream/) generated using SRTM tiles in Maperitive:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

FTP site

ftp.glcf.umiacs.umd.edu

Folder
/glcf/SRTM

I use Filezilla - fast and efficient

Answer (score 2):

Globalmapper is an extremely easy way to download data like this.  They even have a built-in option.  You can then clip, project, and export into a variety of formats.  I realize this is a pay for option, but it is a really valuable tool to have IMHO.

Cheers,
David