# Download new SRTM 30 meters

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, srtm

I read about the new version of the digital elevation model at 30 meters (SRTM 30 meters), but I can not find from were I can download it.

some sources:

http://glcfapp.glcf.umd.edu:8080/esdi/index.jsp

http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/data.asp

http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a new, 30 meters resolution SRTM DTM coming out. As stated on the NASA JPL [official page](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/),

> The next release is planned for later in 2014, and it is expected to include all of South America plus North America south of the United States.

It is incomplete, for now, it has only limited coverage. You can read an article about SRTM coverages [here](http://glcfapp.glcf.umd.edu/data/srtm/description.shtml) (it's kind of outdated though). You can download the data published so far from the USGS EROS Center's [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) application (Digital Elevation -> SRTM -> SRTM 1 Arc-Second Global).

Comment: This is fantastic news!

Comment: Looking at http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/images/SRTM_Jan2015.gif, most parts of the world seem to be already available.

Answer (score 8):

I answered a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/187416/70317)

> You can download and clip a portion of the SRTM 30m DEM with one
>   command with the
>   [elevation](http://elevation.bopen.eu/en/stable/quickstart.html)
>   Python command line tool.
>
> Install it and perform the self check with:
>
> ```
> $ pip install elevation
> ```
>
> Check if you have all the dependencies installed (mainly GDAL tools):
>
> ```
> $ eio selfcheck
> ```
>
> Download and clip a portion of the SRTM 30m DEM giving bounding box as
>   WGS84 coordinates:
>
> ```
> $ eio clip -o Rome-DEM.tif --bounds 12.35 41.8 12.65 42
> ```