# python script automate download SRTM data through looping

Tags: python, gdal, dem, srtm, download

i want to download the DEM data SRTM of the world automatically using python script. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/downloading-srtm-data) on using curl to download SRTM data.  You could implement the accepted answer in Python by using [PyCurl](http://pycurl.io/).  Alternatively use Python's [wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget) utility.

Personally, I did a very similar thing but used the [bulk download facility](http://landsat.usgs.gov/bulk_download_request.php) which became available a couple of years ago.  This gave me a huge list of urls.  Using [DownLoadThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) meant I needed no coding (DTA is available as a plugin to Google and Firefox too).

Comment: Isn't there a cap to the number of tiles you can download using earthexplorer+bulk download utility? I would like to extract all SRTM30 data for Europe but I can't seem to be able to extract more that 100 tiles...

Comment: At the time of writing (3 years ago) I was able to download the whole planet.  I haven't tried recently.  Note however, that I used the bulk download facility to generate a list of URLs and then used DownLoadThemAll to actually do the downloading.  From memory, I do recall building a list of urls in Excel and doing some editting there - so it is possible I accumulated sets of 100 - but this was 3 years ago so my meory is a bit sketchy.